# It there a way to chose which build variant to build?

Tags: android, gradle

I have android lib module (with native implementation). When I build the app (as debug) it also build this lib module (as debug) and as a result of lib build I get `.aar` (as a debug). All is fine here, I try to build debug and I get debug `.aar`.

Then, I need to build this android lib without the whole android app, just this lib. In order to do it I open `Gradle` tab at the right side in Android Studio window then I found my lib name -> Tasks -> build -> assemble. And this gradle task make a build for only this lib.

Issue is that as a result I get two `.aar` files one debug and one release. I don't need to get two I would like to have an option to choose what to build - debug or release.

Main issue here that it takes a lot of time for build this lib in debug and in release. Because of this I would like to choose how to build and it should save a time.

So, how to do it?

Comment: Hi, I think just `assemble` builds all variants and build types... you could try with `assembleDebug`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are building all variant it will take time so You can use android build comment ./gradlew :app:assembleDebug or ./gradlew :app:assembleRelease . Run comment in your application root folder

NB:- if you application not in app folder means submodule use corresponding folder name instead of app  ./gradlew ::assembleDebug